# Windows Server Hyper-V guests cannot see each other on network

Tags: hyper-v, windows

I have a Hyper-V physical machine along with two standard laptops running within my LAN (connected by an ASUS-RT56U router). The physical server runs Windows Hyper-V Server 2008 R2, with two Windows Server 2008 R2 (full) guest VMs installed and running within.

Both laptops run Windows 7. All OSs are 64-bit.

Opening up *Network* in Windows Explorer on either of the two laptops displays both of the laptops in the LAN fine. However, neither of the guest VMs on the server (nor the host itself) are displayed. Indeed, the guest VMs can not see *each other* in *Network* view either. I can ping all computers (laptops and servers) without problems from within the LAN, but all of the servers are simply not visible from anywhere.

In addition, the *Network Map* screen (accessible via Network and Sharing centre) gives me an error message:

> "An error happened during the mapping process."

And I'm suspecting this *might* have something to do with how LLTP (Link Layer Topology Protocol) is working on the network. Worth noting though is that before my server was on the network, the *Network Map* screen displayed fine (as far as I can remember).

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] what is on-topic here. This is not.

Comment: Okay, it's in a "professional setting" if that matters. Personally I don't see the difference, since I'm *not* a pedant.

Comment: Have you disabled the firewall and started the Server Browser service? Do other services work except ICMP? What have you tried and checked? And dozens of other questions ...

Comment: Yes, disabled firewall and started the service. Not sure about serices other than ICMP. I've confirmed many things, including that it's a Private network and Network Discovery is enabled... many I can't remember, because I've been troubleshooting for days now.

Comment: Interesting. I *did* enabled Network Discovery on both servers (guest VMs), but it mediately switches off for some reason.

Comment: Why was this closed, can I ask?!

Comment: Please read my first comment and the grey block down here for an explanation.

Comment: I suspect this got close primarily because the technology you are asking about `LLTP` is aimed at consumers, and not networking professionals, or 'enterprise' networks.  This technology is disabled by default on Windows domains.  I am very confused about why you need this, or what 'security permissions' you would be setting based on the map.  Your question is focused on the symptom, instead of what you are need to do, it is hard to figure out what is going on, or why this 'error' should even matter.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the "SSDP Discovery", "Function Discovery Resource Publication",
and "UPnP Device Host" services on the Windows Servers. Then enable Network discovery.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In fact, I just very recently found the MSDN thread that suggested it. I now have Network discovery successfully enabled (and staying that way), but still no luck with everything else. Also, running `net view` from the command-line still gives the "system error 53 has occurred the network" message.

Comment: I guess I have to ask, why do you even care? The network discovery junk is flaky at best, and you can just run `\\servername` to view shares and printer on the servers...

Comment: Unfortunately I need *Network Map* to work so that other locations are recognised on my network and I can thus set up security permissions appropriately.